# Is there a way to remove Firefox window borders?

Tags: firefox, window, border

The surrounding borders of the Firefox windows. I would like to view the page with screen width when on full-screen..

Answer (score 6):

Try pressing F11. (That will start full screen mode.)

Comment: Okay I'll check that out.. F11 maintains the borders (left, right and bottom), they are tiny ~3px.. and I have firebug installed.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Firefox only has borders on the top and any scrollbars that are there when in full screen. If you have a left border, the All-in-one sidebar extension is responsible, and I think Firebug sometimes creates a bottom border.